# Can an animated tower shield be used as total cover while still allowing a character to attack in the same round?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, equipment

In reading the description of a tower shield it states it can be used to provide total cover, though you must give up your attacks to do so. An animated shield indicates it still imposes all normal penalties associated with shield use naming specifically armor check penalties, arcane spell failure chance,and non-proficiency. Could someone using an animated tower shield attack during their turn then command the shield to animate and act as total cover? Or would "all normal penalties of shield use" negate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving up your attack to enter total cover is an action that must be initiated by the wielder and is considered a "normal penalty of shield use" so yes, it would still stop you from attacking.

An animated shield

> protects you as if you were wielding it.

With whatever downsides that includes.